Example of a residuated prelinear lattice that isn't linear
A residuated lattice is an algebra
$$(L,\land, \lor, \star,\Rightarrow,0,1)$$
with four binary operations and two constants such that

$(L,\land,\lor,0,1)$ is a lattice with the largest element 1 and the least element 0
$(L,\star,1)$ is a commutative semigroup with the unit element 1, i.e. $\star$ is
commutative, associative, $1 \star x = x \star 1=x$ for all $x \in L$
$z \leq( x \Rightarrow y)$ iff $x \star z \leq y$ for all $x,y,z$

A residuated lattice is linear if for each $x, y \in L$ either $ x\leq y$ or $y \leq x$.
A residuated lattice is a MTL-algebra iff the following prelinearity condition holds for any $x,y \in L$
$$(x \Rightarrow y) \lor (y \Rightarrow x) \,=\, 1$$
Trivially, any linear lattice is prelinear but the converse is not true in general. Is there a counterexample to this statement? Is there a residuated lattice that is prelinear but not linear?

You can verify that any Boolean algebra is a residuated lattice where $\star$ is the meet operation ($\wedge$) and
$$x \to y = x' \vee y.$$
Then we certainly have
$$(x\to y) \vee (y \to x) = (x' \vee y) \vee (y' \vee x) = (x \vee x') \vee (y \vee y') = 1.$$

Thank you for replying. I have two questions: is x' the negation of x? And is there a non linear Boolean algebra? (from what I could tell any Boolean algebra with $\land$ and $\to$ as you defined is prelinear)

@MtSet Yes for the first question: $x'$ is the same as $\neg x$ or $\bar{x}$, possibly among other notations. For the second, the answer is again yes, very clearly; indeed, any Boolean algebra with more than 2 elements is not linear.

@MtSet: if you're not familiar with Boolean algebras (unusual, but seen it happen), here's an explicit example: take the four subsets ${0,1}$ with subset inclusion as the lattice ordering. These form a Boolean algebra, but clearly not a linear one, since ${0}$ and ${1}$ are incomparable.

@amrsa thank you!

@Z.A.K. thank you! The concrete example really helped me.
